# Package issue with Ubuntu 10.10 and passenger requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, phusion-passenger, apt

I'm trying to get Passenger working with [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat), and I'm running into a problem. It seems that the Passenger installer is not recognizing the virtual package. I'm getting this error:

Code:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
...
* OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
...
```

And then it says, run this:

```
* To install OpenSSL support for Ruby:
   Please run apt-get install libopenssl-ruby as root.
```

When I run the above command, it refers to the libruby package:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libruby' instead of 'libopenssl-ruby'
libruby is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
```

When I look at the details for libruby, it says it provides libopenssl-ruby:

Code:

```
Provides: libbigdecimal-ruby, libcurses-ruby, libdbm-ruby, libdl-ruby, libdrb-ruby, liberb-ruby, libgdbm-ruby, libiconv-ruby, libopenssl-ruby, libpty-ruby, libracc-runtime-ruby, libreadline-ruby, librexml-ruby, libsdbm-ruby, libstrscan-ruby, libsyslog-ruby, libtest-unit-ruby, libwebrick-ruby, libxmlrpc-ruby, libyaml-ruby, libzlib-ruby
```

And when I rerun the Passenger installer, it gives the same error:

Code:

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
...
* OpenSSL support for Ruby... not found
...
```

Let me know if you need more info. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably didn't compile SSL support when you installed Ruby. This could happen because you didn't have the `libssl-dev` or `openssl` packages installed first off. I recommend installing these packages and then re-compiling your Ruby version and trying again.